# Do not allow a combobox dropdownlist to close when clicked outside of it

Tags: c#, combobox

I am displaying all of the worlds countries in a combobox called `countrybox`.

A second combobox contains all of the cities in a country called `citybox`.

When you choose a country, `citybox` appears and when you open `countrybox`, `citybox` dissapears again.

The problem arises when you open `citybox` and click outside of it.

`citybox` dissapears when you 
open `countrybox` and does not come back when you click outside of `countrybox`.

I tried with this:

```
string ctext { get; set; }

private void countrybox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        citybox.Visible = true;
        string ctext = countrybox.Text;
}


private void countrybox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (countrybox.Text == ctext)
        {
            citybox.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            citybox.Visible = false;
        }
```

However, this did not work as i wanted it to.

Im guessing it is because the Combobox class does not recognize a click outside of the box as a _DropDownClosed event.

I have also tried with using the 
validating event to check if a user clicks on the form

```
 private void countrybox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.Equals((sender as Form).Name, @"Form1") && string.IsNullOrEmpty(countrybox.Text))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("You have to select a country!");
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway to make the combobox dropdownlist to not close when clicked outside of the list?

I apologize if i have any Spelling misstakes, my native language is not English.

**Posting my full code below for people who want more details.**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] Countries = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Travelbureau\Countries.txt");
        Array.Sort(Countries);
        for (int i = 0; i < Countries.Length; i++)
        {
            countrybox.Items.Add(Countries[i]);
        }
    }
    string ctext { get; set; }

    private void countrybox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        citybox.Visible = true;
        string ctext = countrybox.Text;

        switch (countrybox.Text)
        {
            case "Afghanistan":
            string[] AfgCity = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Travelbureau\Afghanistan.txt");
            Array.Sort(AfgCity);
            for (int i = 0; i < AfgCity.Length; i++)
            {
                citybox.Items.Add(AfgCity[i]);
            }
            break;
            default:
            citybox.Text = "City";
            citybox.Items.Clear();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void countrybox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        citybox.Visible = false;
    }

    private void countrybox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (countrybox.Text == ctext)
        {
            citybox.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            citybox.Visible = false;
      }
    private void countrybox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        countrybox.Text = "";
        citybox.Visible = false;
    }

    private void citybox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        citybox.Text = "";
    }

    private void countrybox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.Equals((sender as Form).Name, @"Form1") && string.IsNullOrEmpty(countrybox.Text))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("You have to select a country!");
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did anything with Windows Forms, but you should be able to accomplish this with the `Validating` event. If you check in that to see whether it has a value and set `e.Cancel` accordingly, I believe that will give you your desired behavior.

In my experience, it's a very good idea to set some sort of status visible to the user in that event, though. It can be confusing when a user is no longer able to click anywhere. You can do that with a `MessageBox` or a `Label`. But that's really a UX matter that isn't directly relevant to your question.

You might also have to set a property that indicates that it should validate when you leave the control, but I don't believe that's the case. If someone knows for sure I'll update this answer to reflect that.

And yes, you can change the visibility of `cityBox` in that method as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that doesn't stop the user to click outside of `countrybox`. It only works when clicking on other objects such as buttons and not if you click on the form itself